# Specify subclass mapping for Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

[The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) for inheritance explains how to easily implement STI given that you can choose the values for the `type` column.

However, I have a legacy DB, and these values already exist. Let's say those are `PRIORITY`, `ECONOMY`, and `FLEXI`, how do I specify how to map these values to subclasses?

```
class PriorityPassenger < Passenger
  # map to PRIORITY
end
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if one decides to go with monkey patching, [this guy](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/86be4bfe37f8adc576b6895093656b63c2438d30/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb#L186) is better candidate. Also, `prepend MyMonkey` would be better than direct monkeypatching of the re-opened class.

Comment: @mudasobwa: yes, that method seems to be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (untested):

```
ActiveRecord::Inheritance::ClassMethods.prepend(Module.new do
  def find_sti_class(type_name)
    case type_name
    when 'PRIORITY' then PriorityPassenger
    ...
    else super(type_name)
    end
  end
end)
```

Comment: Stupid question: where does this code go? In the Passenger class, in an independent file?

Comment: In some `initializer`, sooner is better.

Comment: I've put that code (with my values) in a new file under `config/initializers`, and now I get `undefined method `attributes_builder' for "PriorityPassenger":String`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I accidentally put `PriorityPassenger` in quotes, which is wrong; it should be the class constant indeed. I have updated an answer.